# "cargo run --release --features "mainnet" --example permanode $CONFIGPATH/config.tom " seems failed

Tags: permanode

Cargo command seems to be failed while the error below appears.
Can you help me out ?

thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', permanode/main.rs:140:28
[image]

Comment: can you run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1`? That may give an insight what file is not found.

Comment: Also, I assume you have already verified that `$CONFIGPATH/config.tom` resolves to a file that actually exists?

Answer (score 3):

i think you just lost the last char of the [toml](https://toml.io/en/) file extension: "L"

Try:

```
cargo run --release --features ”mainnet“ --example permanode $CONFIGPATH/config.toml
```

and ensure that the path to your config file is correct.